# Importing a module in python without running the contents of the module every time

Tags: python, import, module

I'm a programming and python noob so please explain as simply as you can.

I have a program file where I obtain a neural network. This neural network changes on every run of the program due to using random training data. This file is called "main.py"

I use the obtained neural network on another program file to make some more calculations and modifications. At the start of the code, I utilize:

```
import main
```

However, every time I run the code, it also runs main.py and changes the obtained output. I would like to run main.py only once so the imported output remains consistent. How can I possibly do this?

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your module `main.py` you should add the line `if __name__ == "__main__"`, i.e.:

```py
# main.py

def foo():
    # function body

# do NOT call foo here.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # call foo here.
    foo()
```

In this way when you import the module `main` the function `foo` will not run.

For instance, in the module 'other.py' you can import the function `foo` from the module `main`:

```
from main import foo

# do stuff with foo
```

Comment: Hi, when I do this, I still have to call the function foo() in 'other.py' right if I have to use the values returned by foo(). This would mean that foo() would once again run with random data that would change the output obtained. Am I wrong?